error:0A0000BF:SSL routines::no protocols available
error:0A0000BF:SSL routines::no protocols available with Openssl v 3.1.4 where as it works fine with  openssl1.1.1?docker image dotnet8.0-alpine using openssl 3.1.4 its not working whereas .net6.0 image using openssl1.1.1 so with that image no ssl_error any help is much appreciated
made Cipherstring default SECLVEVEL to 0 works but that is not recommeneded from security perspective, need alternative here, installing openssl 1.1.1 for dotnet 8.0-alpine image or any such other alternatives

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
